# ESCs for inverted flight?

Tags: recommendations, esc

What types of brushless drone ESCs are reversible and will work for flying inverted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ESCs loaded with recent versions of BLHeli (`BLHELI_S` and `BLHELI_32`) will support reversible motor direction, either through Dshot commands (*obviously only supported when using Dshot signaling*) or with zero-throttle centered around the middle throttle position, 1500µs (*supports Oneshot/Multishot in addition to Dshot*).

These modes can be set up in the BLHELI Suite configurator.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern BLHeli_S and BLHeli32 ESCs are reversible, though more robust escs will help prevent desyncs. Check out zoefpv for 3D stuff.